# "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} vs. ${debian_chroot}"

Tags: bash, shell-script

In ~/.bashrc I have

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Instead why can't it be

```
PS1='${debian_chroot}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

It would accomplish the same thing. Wouldn't it?

Comment: See [What does “${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}” do in my terminal prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/a/372876)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the same, note the parenthesis:

```
$ var=foo
$ echo "${var} ${var:+($var)}"
foo (foo)
```

The `:+` expansion is there so that those aren't printed if the var is empty.

Comment: I accept your answer. The reason I couldn't see it myself was that I had the pre-conceived notion that the parenthesis were going to disappear as a result of some Bash expansion.

Comment: @SamehRamzyLabib, yeah. It looks a bit like command substitution `$(...)` here, but I don't think the parens are special in any `${...}` expansion. (I might forget something.) Zsh does use them for glob qualifiers etc., though.

Comment: @SamehRamzyLabib if you accept the answer, then please formally do so by clicking the checkmark underneat the up/down arrows next to this answer. It's the way it works here and also gives a reward (in reputation) to the person having given the answer.